# When writing a PowerShell module in C#, how do I store module state?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell module in C# that connects to a database. The module has a `Get-MyDatabaseRecord` cmdlet which can be used to query the database. If you have a `PSCredential` object in the variable `$MyCredentials`, you can call the cmdlet like so:

```
PS C:\> Get-MyDatabaseRecord -Credential $MyCredentials -Id 3


MyRecordId    : 3
MyRecordValue : test_value
```

The problem is, having to specify the `Credential` parameter every time that you call `Get-MyDatabaseRecord` is tedious and inefficient. It would be better if you could just call one cmdlet to connect to the database, and then another to get the record:

```
PS C:\> Connect-MyDatabase -Credential $MyCredentials
PS C:\> Get-MyDatabaseRecord -Id 3


MyRecordId    : 3
MyRecordValue : test_value
```

In order for that to be possible, the `Connect-MyDatabase` cmdlet has to store the database connection object somewhere so that the `Get-MyDatabaseRecord` cmdlet can obtain that object. How should I do this?

### Ideas I've thought of

#### Use a static variable

I could just define a static variable somewhere to contain the database connection:

```
static class ModuleState
{
    internal static IDbConnection CurrentConnection { get; set; }
}
```

However, global mutable state is usually a bad idea. Could this cause problems somehow, or is this a good solution?

(One example of a problem would be if multiple PowerShell sessions somehow shared the same instance of my assembly. Then all of the sessions would inadvertently share a single `CurrentConnection` property. But I don't know if this is actually possible.)

#### Use PowerShell module session state

The MSDN page "[Windows PowerShell Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" talks about something called session state. The page says that "session-state data" contains "session-state variable information", but it doesn't go into detail about what this information is or how to access it.

The page also says that [the `SessionState` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.sessionstate%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to access session-state data. This class contains a property called [`PSVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.sessionstate.psvariable%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), of type [`PSVariableIntrinsics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psvariableintrinsics%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, I have two problems with this. The first problem is that accessing the `SessionState` property requires me to inherit from `PSCmdlet` instead of `Cmdlet`, and I'm not sure if I want to do that.

The second problem is that I can't figure out how to make the variable private. Here's the code that I'm trying:

```
const int TestVariableDefault = 10;
const string TestVariableName = "TestVariable";

int TestVariable
{
    get
    {
        return (int)SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue(TestVariableName,
            TestVariableDefault);
    }
    set
    {
        PSVariable testVariable = new PSVariable(TestVariableName, value,
            ScopedItemOptions.Private);
        SessionState.PSVariable.Set(testVariable);
    }
}
```

The `TestVariable` property works just as I would expect. But despite the fact that I'm using `ScopedItemOptions.Private`, I can still access this variable at the prompt by typing in `$TestVariable`, and the variable is listed in the output of `Get-Variable`. I want my variable to be hidden from the user.

Comment: This other question is asking more or less the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513822/what-is-the-best-practice-for-keeping-state-between-calls-to-powershell-cmdlets

Answer (score 6):

One approach would be to use a cmdlet or function that outputs a connection object. This object could be simply the PSCredential object, or it could contain the credential and other information like a connection string. You're saving this in a variable now and you can continue to do this, but you can also use $PSDefaultParamterValues to store this value and pass it to all the appropriate cmdlets in the module.

I've never written a C# module but I've done something similar in PS:

```
function Set-DefaultCredential
{
    param
    (
        [PSCredential]
        $Credential
    )

    $ModuleName = (Get-Item -Path $PSScriptRoot).Parent.Name
    $Module = Get-Module -Name $ModuleName
    $Commands = $Module.ExportedCommands.GetEnumerator()  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
    foreach ($Command in $Commands)
    {
        $Global:PSDefaultParameterValues["$Command`:Credential"] = $Credential
    }
}
```

This code sets the credential you've passed in as the default for any of the exported commands of my module using the $PSDefaultParameterValues automatic variable. Of course your logic may not be the same but it might show you the approach.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this doesn't answer the question, but this does seem like a good solution to my problem. I've awarded you the bounty. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It sounds like you really would like to restrict the variable you've created to the module scope, correct? Have you written a module manifest? If you create a variable in the module code, you can control it's visibility outside of the module using the VariablesToExport property of the manifest.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar thoughts, but never had the need to build a full and clean implementation.   One approach to storing state that seemed appropriate for my connections was to encapsulate that state in a PSDrive.   The such drives are integrated into session state.

The docs aren't always obvious on this, but it involves writing a class that derives from `DriveCmdletProvider`, which has built-in support for credential management.  As I remember it, the `NewDrive` method can return a custom class derived from `PSDriveInfo` with additional members, including private or internal members, to store what you need.

You can then use `New-PSDrive` and `Remove-PSDrive` to establish/break connections connection with a drive name.  Dynamic parameters provided by the `DriveCmdletProvider` let you customize parameters to `New-PSDrive` for your specifics.

See [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.provider.drivecmdletprovider.newdrive(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the easiest way is to just make an advanced function in ps and use $script:mycred

But if u need to stick to pure c# and support multiple runspaces, it may be possible to make a dictionary of runspace ids and  tokens

```
public static class TokenCollection {
    public static readonly Dictionary<Guid,PSObject> Tokens = new Dictionary<Guid,PSObject>();
}
```

You then add your current runspace guid inside with your token

```
Guid runspId = Guid.Empty;
using (var runsp = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace))
{
    runspId = runsp.Runspace.InstanceId;
    TokenCollection.Add(runspId, token);
}
```

Get a token like this

```
PSObject token = null;
if (TokenCollection.Tokens.ContainsKey(runspaceId))
{
    token = TokenCollection.Tokens[runspId];
}
```